# How to make a clickable link that executes a command with bukkit

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to make a [bukkit](http://bukkit.org) plugin and I can't seem to find any documentation on this but I've seen it done, How would I input commands into a chat message that a user could click on to execute a command on the server like "/motd" in the form of a clickable link like a URL

```
if (commandLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("cmd") {
    player.sendMessage("Pick a command: " + </motd> + ", " + </mail> );
}
```

replacing "" and "" to output something like this:

Pick a command: [MOTD](/motd), [Mail](/mail)

and clicking them would execute the command to the server as them. How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
IChatBaseComponent comp = ChatSerializer
            .a("{\"text\":\"" + "Choose one: " + "\",\"extra\":[{\"text\":\"" + "MOTD" + "\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"" + "/motd" + "\"}}]}");
    
PacketPlayOutChat packet = new PacketPlayOutChat(comp, true);
((CraftPlayer) <player>).getHandle().playerConnection.sendPacket(packet);
```

This would send them a message showing:

```
Choose one: MOTD
```

and when the user clicked `MOTD`, it would run the command `/motd` as the player. Here's a little breakdown of what we're actually doing:

```
    IChatBaseComponent comp = ChatSerializer
            .a("{\"text\":\"" + "<Ignored Message> " + 
            "\",\"extra\":[{\"text\":\"" + "<Message that will be clicked>" + 
            "\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"" + 
            "<Command to be run when message is clicked>" + "\"}}]}");
    
PacketPlayOutChat packet = new PacketPlayOutChat(comp, true);
((CraftPlayer) <player>).getHandle().playerConnection.sendPacket(packet);
```

The above code will send the player:

```
<Ignored Message> <Message that will be clicked>
```

and when the player clicks `<Message that will be clicked>`

they will run the command `<Command to be run when a message is clicked>`, and because it does not start with the command prefix, `/`, it will force them to chat `<Command to be run when a message is clicked>`.

Unfortunately, as far as I know, you can only put one click event per message, so you would have to do something like this:

> Choose one:
>
> MOTD
> Mail

So you would have to do, where the variable `player` is the player:

```
player.sendMessage("Choose one:");

IChatBaseComponent comp = ChatSerializer
            .a("{\"text\":\"" + 
            "\",\"extra\":[{\"text\":\"" + "MOTD" + 
            "\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"" + 
            "/motd" + "\"}}]}");    
PacketPlayOutChat packet = new PacketPlayOutChat(comp, true);
((CraftPlayer) player).getHandle().playerConnection.sendPacket(packet);

IChatBaseComponent comp2 = ChatSerializer
            .a("{\"text\":\"" + 
            "\",\"extra\":[{\"text\":\"" + "Mail" + 
            "\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"" + 
            "/mail" + "\"}}]}");    
PacketPlayOutChat packet2 = new PacketPlayOutChat(comp2, true);
((CraftPlayer) player).getHandle().playerConnection.sendPacket(packet2);
```

When `MOTD` is clicked, `/motd` will be run by the player, and when `Mail` is clicked, `/mail` will be run.

Just as a side note, you will need to include `craftbukkit` in your build path, along with `bukkit` to do this

Comment: This works great, bummer about the per line but it does work with a tiny modification I edited on your post. with "comp"

Answer (score 0):

Or you could simply just do this (I did my own, You can edit it)

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ tellraw @p ["",{"text":"Click this to die","color":"dark_red","bold":true,"clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/kill @p"},"hoverEvent":{"action":"show_text","value":{"text":"","extra":[{"text":"Kills you!"}]}}}]
```

run_command can be replaced with Open URL too.

You can replace dark red with any colour too. You can replace true with false for bold if you want, /kill @p can be replaced with a command (Or a https:// link if you do Open URL, show_text can be replaced with Show Item, Show entity, or Show Achivement. Text & Kills you can be replaced with the different thing (eg, Show entity) (Entity replaces text)

I found a website if your stuck! Good day :) http://minecraftjson.com/

Comment: using command blocks or typing it myself in world that would be fine but I was using the bukkit api so this wouldn't be very helpful in that case.